# Unable to run certain Python files from Terminal. Permission denied?

Tags: python, terminal

What causes the below error?

```
-bash: ./proj.py: Permission denied
```

I have one file, called `projsol.py`, that runs perfectly out of terminal when I enter `./projsol.py --summary *.html` in Terminal.

However, when I enter `./proj.py --summary *.html`, I get the above error. I've literally copied and pasted the entire context of `projsol.py` into `proj.py`, tried running the command again, and it still gives me the above bash error. What's causing this?

Note: I am *very* new to programming, and have very unfamiliar with Terminal and Python, so please explain in layman's terms (it's much appreciated!).

Comment: There are a few permission bits for the ability to “execute” files. You can use `chmod +x proj.py` or `python proj.py --summary *.html`.

Comment: @minitech but i don't understand why the same command (minus the file name) works for one file and not the other, even though the contents and location are exactly the same.

Comment: The other one has different permissions on it, i.e. something already did the `chmod +x`.

Answer (score 4):

Run the chmod command against the file in the following manner:

```
sudo chmod +x proj.py
```

This assigns the executable bit to the file.

If that doesn't work run the following command, from the same directory as proj.py, and provide the output

```
ls -al
```

This will give you a dump of the directory as well as permissions and user/group permissions on the file. Something is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be having sufficient permissions to execute that file.
Please check your file permissions by running the following command

```
ls -al
```

it will give the output which defines permissions which is defined for that file 
Should look something like this

```
-rwxrw-r--   1 <fileowner>  110247009  1276 Sep 28 15:43 <yourfilename>
```

take a look at this article to understand the output https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/ls-file-permissions.html

you can change the permissions/ownership of the file using chmod/chown command 
refer to those command's man pages for more details. hope this helps